# how to keep my propagating solution of pde always in center of the computational domain?

Tags: matlab, events, solver, ode, pde

I have a pde $$u_{tt} + u_t = u_{xx} - \sin(u)  + f$$ which is defined on an unbounded sample (no boundaries). I could solve it in matlab by means of method of lines with solution in a matrix form of u(t,x). the problem is since my solution is a propagating one and my computational domain is finite, very soon the interested part of the solution gets out of the domain and I am no longer able to see it. here is part of my code and suggestions that I was never able to put it in code.

```
x = [-10:0.1:10];    
u0 = asin(f) + 4*atan(exp(x));   
[t,u] = ode113(@pde,[t0 tf],u0, options);
plot(x,u(end,:));
```

This is just a few lines of my code to let you know that the solution is a kink which is moving under the action of the force "f" to either right or left. How can I have the kink in the center for all the time of integration?
I came up with this idea to get help from the 'event' function as option of ode solvers and detect my solution whenever it gets away a specific distance from the center, but did not know what else I should do.

Comment: Could you redefine `x` to be `x-k*t` where `k` is the speed of the wave?

Comment: I can't say yes nor I would say no. First of all, I do not know the speed of my wave, secondly, could you please be more specific how I can apply this as a code, and how I would plot it.